# Add exception in firewall using java program

Tags: java, firewall

Does anyone know how to add an exception to a firewall using a java program?
Because when I upload a photo using a java program and a firewall is turned on, then many times it creates a problem and the photo was not uploaded.

Does someone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will need to look at windows APIs to do that via JNI calls. With lucky you'll find some java library that already implements this functionality...

Comment: First things first: is the firewall on the client side (on the same machine where the uploader runs) or on the server side? If on the client side: what kind of firewall and OS is that?

Comment: Is the question how to add an exception to a firewall that will allow a Java program to upload a photo, or is it how to programmatically, from Java, change a firewall?

Comment: A firewall would be pretty useless if you could override it with your program.

Comment: @bpgergo: Yes firewall on the client side. And we can't say specific OS used by client. Because they use all OS such as Mac, Windows, or Linux.

Comment: @filipenf: If possible can you share some link?

Comment: Each operating system will have it's own way to do that, in windows you'll call windows api's to add a firewall exception ( I'm guessing ) and OS will ask the end-user if they want to do that. In Linux it's possible to change iptables rules, but you will need permissions for that also. I have a mac but never used it's firewall features so no idea... Anyway this thing is very OS specific so it is possible that you will need to write a portability layer for that... I wish you good look with that :-)

Comment: @filipenf: Thanks for your answer. I will try and move on find the OS related stuff for firewall. :-)